# What is the best way to embed binary value in String

Tags: stanza

I would like to use escape to represent control code to build a message with terminal color.

Can I use something like...

```
"\u001b[93m" or "\x1b[93m"
```

?

Comment: Try to be more verbose , what programming language are you using etc..

Comment: @Sameh: It's in the tag. Did you read it?

Comment: My bad i missed it .

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using this method:

```
val newargs = append-all([to-string(to-char(27)) CGREEN msg to-string(to-char(27)) CEND])
```

to-string(to-char(27)) is too clumsy.
I am sure there is a better method.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how [this library](https://github.com/tylanphear/term-colors) implements terminal colors as a reference

Comment: Thanks, the library is very useful, but it is not exactly the answer to my question. I see that val ESCAPE = to-char(0x1B) is used. I wanted an escape method on a String. I notice "\nABC\n" works but it seems that "\x1bABC" does not.

Comment: I don't think that is currently supported in stanza, only a subset of common escape sequences are handled by the parser.